# Is GCM with zero-length AAD less secure?

Tags: authenticated-encryption, gcm, aes-gcm

In a previous [question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/72979/aead-for-aes128-gcm-is-it-necessary-to-add-a-zero-length-aad%3E), it was made clear that in the case of GCM, there is no distinction between "no AAD" and "zero-length AAD".  Since I have noticed "zero-length AAD" in several implementations, my question is, does that render such AE schemes less secure?

In the various papers that treat AE security, I think the paper [Reconsidering Generic Composition by Namprempre, Rogaway and Shrimpton](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F978-3-642-55220-5_15.pdf) might have been the most explicit in this regard.  According to their nAE scheme enumeration, the first scheme that shows weaker security bounds is A9 where A (i.e. AAD) is dropped from the Tag computation (see Fig. 5).  Now of course, they do mention that it's a borderline case (transitional). But they make it clear that its security is not as tight as the A1-A8 schemes (all of which include A in the tag calculation).  I have tried to survey other papers on the topic, but I haven't found a paper that gives a similar treatment.

So if AAD is missing from GCM (or if |AAD|=0), is GCM security downgraded in any way or is our security proof a bit weaker?  Or, is that not a conclusion we should take from Namprempre's paper above (assuming their results were accepted by the crypto community)?

Comment: As [noted](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59377989#59377989): GCM is A5 on the paper.

Comment: GCM doesn't support noAAD. In GCM, the AAD with zero-length is converted to 128 zeroes. This is clear from the previous answer and NIST's doc. **There is always an AAD! in GCM** The recipient, therefore, can reject any empty AAD as a forgery. This provides an additional check since AAD is authenticated but not encrypted. If you are asking to modify the CGM to remove AAD, then this is a different scheme.

Comment: I'm reading the previous answer differently.  For example, he says, "If the AAD is zero-length, then zero bits of padding are added and no time is spent hashing any AAD or AAD padding".  From that I conclude that AAD with zero-length is converted to zero bits of zeros, not 128 bits of zeros.  I think the rest of his answer makes it clearer.  If |AAD|=0, then len(A)=0, v=0, and 0^v=0, "**thus the number of ‘0’ bits appended is 0**".  He then concludes that "if A is empty, then the prefix A∥0^v is also empty."  This means that all the A-components in creating GHASH are empty (A, 0^v, len(A)).

Comment: Yes, that is correct, $A || 0^v$ is empty, however, the length is encoded in 64 bits so that one can decode it as empty AAD. So, still, there is always AAD in GCM.

Comment: Even empty AAD gives a little halt option against AAD removal from an adversary. So effectively, they are not.

Comment: I see.  So it's the component [len(A)]64 that remains.  I checked the NIST doc; they define [x]64 as the binary representation of integer x (in this case, x=0) as a string of 64 bits.  So I guess I have to agree.  One more clarification from the author of the previous answer if you can, I was a bit confused about his first statement "AES-GCM does not support ‘no AAD’ as distinct from ‘zero-length AAD’".  I sort of read it as, in the case of GCM we don't make a distinction between 'no AAD' and 'zero-length AAD'.  Did I read wrong?

Comment: No ADD should be something like that; there is no information available about AAD, even length or single bit. However, in this case, the non-existence of AAD may indicate that it is erased or already noAAD. The scheme should distinguish this. GCM simply encodes the length and doesn't allow noAAD ( or we can say converts noADD into zero-length AAD).

Comment: Got it.  So no-AAD here means no information about AAD, not that AAD logic is dropped.  I think we're in total agreement now.  Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AES-GCM falls category A5 in the paper. In AES-GCM doesn't support $\texttt{no-AAD}$, even you don't use AAD during encryption, AES-GCM convert his as a $\texttt{zero-length-AAD}$.

See in the NIST [Special Publication 800-38d, page 15](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/SP/nistspecialpublication800-38d.pdf#page=15);

> Algorithm 4: $GCM-AE_K (IV, P, A)$
> …
> 4. Let $u = 128\cdot\lceil\operatorname{len}(C)/128\rceil - \operatorname{len}(C)$ and let $v = 128\cdot\lceil\operatorname{len}(A)/128\rceil - \operatorname{len}(A)$.
> 5. Define a block, $S$, as follows: $$S = \operatorname{GHASH}_H(\mathbf{A \mathbin\| \mathtt 0^v} \mathbin\| C \mathbin\| \mathtt 0^u \mathbin\| \mathbf{[\operatorname{len}(A)]_{64}} \mathbin\| [\operatorname{len}(C)]_{64}).$$
> …
> In Steps 4 and 5, the AAD and the ciphertext are each appended with the minimum number of ‘$\mathtt 0$’ bits, **possibly none**, so that the bit lengths of the resulting strings are multiples of the block size (The bolds, are mine).

$A$ is associated data, $len(A) = 0$ therefore, $\mathtt{v} = 0$. Even in this case, we have $[\operatorname{len}(A)]_{64}$, this 64-bit encoding of the length of th associated data and this will always indicate the exsitance of AAD, zero-length or not!.

If an attacker, removes the associated data, to make it seem like zero-length, during the decryption, one must halt with the tag mismatch ( Always halt and stop the decryption at once).

A scheme that supports no-AAD, must not carry information about the missing AAD, otherwise, it falls into zero-length AAD.

In the end, we have extra protection against forgeries with zero-length AAD.